# Julia Optimization

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am trying to run a bootstrap in Julia and have coded up a working bootstrap function. However, it is slow and the same code in R runs in half the time. I am sure that there must be some inefficiencies in my code, I am very new to using Julia. I was wondering if anyone could provide me with some advice/suggestions.

Here is the fully reproducible code

```
using DataFrames
using Statistics
using StatsBase

df = DataFrame(rand(1:9, 1000,1000), :auto); # Create data

# Bootstrap function
function bootstrap(;iters=1, data=nothing, statistic=nothing)
    statArr = DataFrame() # Init empty dataframe
    for i in 1:iters
        data_sample = data[sample(1:nrow(data), nrow(data), replace=true), :] # sample the data with replacement
        stat = statistic(data_sample)
        append!(statArr, stat) # push dataframe to empty dataframe
    end
    return statArr
end;

# Statistic function for column means
function meanmap(data)
    return mapcols(col -> mean(col), data)
end;

# Run the bootstrap on the data
@time bootDist = bootstrap(iters = 9999, data = df, statistic = meanmap);
```

This takes around 68 seconds to run it takes 35 seconds in R.

Your advice is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: uff, this looks like it should take a fraction of a second to run. I mean, this is but a million datapoints?

Comment: I agree, I cannot seem to find the bottleneck in the code. Any suggestions?

Comment: what does `statistics()` do, and do you really need it?

Comment: Statistic() is my coded up column means function. It computes the mean of each of the 1000 columns in the data frame. I did try using ```mean(eachcol(data_sample))``` (2nd line in the for loop) but that actually made the performance worse

Comment: doesn't `mean` support something like an axis parameter, or could you transpose the table?

Comment: Looking at the docs mean does support a dims parameter. I am wondering if the data structure of DataFrame is appropriate for a bootstrap, because if I just run the for loop with only re-sampling the data (no statistic calculation or pushing data) then the bootstrap still takes 44 seconds to complete which is still very slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using DataFrames.jl you can do e.g.:

```
function bootstrap(;iters=1, data=nothing, statistic=nothing)
    statArr = Float64.(empty(data)) # Init empty dataframe
    for i in 1:iters
        stat = statistic(data, rand(1:nrow(data), nrow(data)))
        push!(statArr, stat) # push row to empty dataframe
    end
    return statArr
end;

# Statistic function for column means
meanmap(data, sel) = [mean(@view x[sel]) for x in eachcol(data)]
```

Which should be faster than R. The changes are:

- major: use views instead of copying everything in every iteration
- minor: do not create a data frame for each bootstrap replicate but rather a vector and `push!` it instead of `append!`ing it (this saves time of creation and validation of data frame objects)

(I have made only the major optimizations of the code; there are some additional minor optimizations that could be made, but they should not affect the run time in a significant way)

Also note that you are close to the maximum execution speed as:

```
julia> x = rand(1:nrow(df), nrow(df));

julia> y = df[!, 1];

julia> f(y, x) = mean(@view y[x]);

julia> g(y, x) = [f(y, x) for _ in 1:9999*1000];

julia> @time g(y, x);
```

Is roughly the lower bound of execution time you can expect to have and it is not much faster than the code above (it is faster of course, by around 25%-30%, as it does less work and is more CPU cache friendly).

---

As a small comment showing how details matter in such cases (I think it is interesting, although it is a minor optimization, so I left it out).

Instead of `rand(1:nrow(data), nrow(data))` if you use `sort!(rand(1:nrow(data), nrow(data)))` you save an additional 1 second. The reason is that in this way you ensure that you access data sequentially when you calculate `mean` (which is more CPU cache friendly and `mean` is unaffected by observation order).

A second comment like this is that on a multi-CPU machine (and started Julia with `-t` switch selecting to use more than one thread) one could use threading to speed things up like this (again - I did not optimize things out here to the very last possible tweak, but rather wanted to show the main idea):

```
function bootstrap(;iters=1, data=nothing, statistic=nothing)
    statArr = Float64.(empty(data)) # Init empty dataframe
    tmp = Vector{Any}(undef, iters)
    Threads.@threads for i in 1:iters
        stat = statistic(data, rand(1:nrow(data), nrow(data)))
        tmp[i] = stat
    end
    for v in tmp
        push!(statArr, v) # push dataframe to empty dataframe
    end
    return statArr
end
```

This is much faster and easy to do in Julia (while doable, but not so easy in R).

---

Regarding views you can read about them [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Views-(SubArrays-and-other-view-types)).

Comment: Thank you! I can confirm this is faster than R. It takes my machine 16 seconds to complete. I am unfamiliar with views. Can you please suggest a resource, for learning about them?

Comment: I have edited the answer with some additional comments and answer to your question.

Comment: You can get better performance by replacing `tmp` with `Matrix{Float64}(undef, iters, ncol(data))`, assigning `tmp[i, :] = stat`, and then replacing the loop at the end with `statArr .= tmp`, which will assign the whole array in place. With a 100x50 `df`, this gets me down from an original time of 598ms to a final time of 36ms.